# Only Getting 40% Code coverage on Trigger Please Help!

Tags: unit-test, error, before-trigger

I'm trying to update a lookup field on the lead object via trigger, but I'm not getting enough code coverage.  Can someone help me ?

TRIGGER

```
trigger PartnerName on Lead (before insert) {
Map<string, List <Lead>> contactNamesToLeadsMap = new Map<string, List <Lead>>();

    for(Lead ld : trigger.new){
        if(!String.isBlank(ld.name)) {
            List<Lead> leadsForPartner = null;
            if(contactNamesToLeadsMap.containsKey(ld.name)) {
                leadsForPartner = contactNamesToLeadsMap.get(ld.name);
            } else {
                leadsForPartner = new List<Lead>();
                contactNamesToLeadsMap.put(ld.name, leadsForPartner);
            }
            leadsForPartner.add(ld);
        } else {
            ld.Partner_Name__c = null;
        }
    }

    List <Contact> contlist = [select Id, Name from Contact where Name in :contactNamesToLeadsMap.keySet()];

    for(Contact con : contlist) {


        List<Lead> leadsForPartner = contactNamesToLeadsMap.get(con.Name);
        for(Lead ld : leadsForPartner) {
            ld.Partner_Name__c = con.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

APEX CLASS

```
@IsTest
public class LeadPartnerTestClass {
    static testMethod Void LeadPartnerTestClass() {
        //Create an Account
        Account a = new account();
        a.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert a;

        //Create a Contact
        Contact c = new contact();
        c.FirstName = 'Test';
        c.LastName = 'Contact';
        c.AccountId = a.id;
        insert c;

        //Create a "Lead"
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.FirstName= 'Test';
        ld.LastName = 'Contact';
        ld.Company = 'Test Account';
        ld.Partner_Name__c = c.id;
        ld.Status = 'Open';
        insert ld;

        //Query Success
        system.AssertEquals(c.id, ld.Partner_Name__c);
    }
}
```

> **Test Class**

```
@IsTest
public class LeadPartnerTestClass {
    static testMethod Void LeadPartnerTestClass() {
        //Create an Account
        Account a = new account();
        a.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert a;

        //Create a Contact
        Contact con = new contact();
        con.FirstName = 'Test';
        con.LastName = 'Contact';
        con.AccountId = a.id;
        insert con;


        //Create a "Lead"
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.FirstName= 'Test';
        ld.LastName = 'Lead';
        ld.Company = 'Test Account';
        ld.PartnerFirstName__c = 'Test';
        ld.PartnerLastName__c = 'Contact';
        ld.Partner_Name__c = con.id;
        ld.Status = 'Open';
        insert ld;

            //Query Success
        system.AssertEquals(con.id, ld.Partner_Name__c);
    }
}
```

![Code Coverage Screen Shot}(https://app.box.com/s/h2fnibjabfgpn8rvqg7m)

**Updated Test Class**

```
@IsTest
public class LeadPartnerTestClass {

    static testMethod Void LeadPartnerTestClass() {
        list<Lead> leadList = new list<Lead>();

        //Create an Account
        Account a = new account();
        a.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert a;

        //Create a Contact
        Contact con = new contact();
        con.FirstName = 'Test';
        con.LastName = 'Contact';
        con.AccountId = a.id;
        insert con;

        //Create a "Lead"
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.FirstName= 'Test';
        ld.LastName = 'Lead';
        ld.Company = 'Test Account';
        ld.PartnerFirstName__c = 'Test';
        ld.PartnerLastName__c = 'Contact';
        ld.Partner_Name__c= con.id;
        ld.Status = 'Open';
        leadList.add(ld);

        Lead ld2 = new Lead();
        ld2.FirstName= 'Test';
        ld2.LastName = 'Lead2';
        ld2.Company = 'Test Account2';
        ld2.PartnerFirstName__c = null ;
        ld2.PartnerLastName__c = null ;
        ld2.Partner_Name__c= con.id;
        ld2.Status = 'Open';
        leadList.add(ld2);

        Lead ld3 = new Lead();
        ld3.FirstName= 'Test';
        ld3.LastName = 'Lead3';
        ld3.Company = 'Test Account3';
        ld3.PartnerFirstName__c = null ;
        ld3.PartnerLastName__c = null ;
        ld3.Status = 'Open';
        leadList.add(ld3);

        insert leadList;

         //Query Success
        system.AssertEquals(con.id, ld.Partner_Name__c);   
    }
}
```

Comment: What lines aren't getting coverage?

Comment: I updated the code. Just to show the final outcome.  It's getting 100% coverage now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Testing Best Practices [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_best_practices.htm), if you focus on use case as well as bulk record processing the code coverage will follow.

> While only 75% of your Apex code must be covered by tests, your focus
>   shouldn't be on the percentage of code that is covered. Instead, you
>   should make sure that every use case of your application is covered,
>   including positive and negative cases, as well as bulk and single
>   records. This should lead to 75% or more of your code being covered by
>   unit tests.
>
> - In the case of conditional logic (including ternary operators),    execute each branch of code logic.
> - Make calls to methods using both valid and invalid inputs.
> - Complete successfully without throwing any exceptions, unless those    errors are expected and caught in a try…catch block.
> - Always handle all exceptions that are caught, instead of merely    catching the exceptions.
> - Use System.assert methods to prove that code behaves properly.
> - Use the runAs method to test your application in different user    contexts.
> - Exercise bulk trigger functionality—use at least 20 records in your    tests.

If you view which lines are not covered it should give you a better idea of what you are missing. Information on checking coverage can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en_US), but as crmprogdev pointed out you need to make sure your tests enter each branch of your if-else statements. For example your test record has a name so the else(`ld.Partner_Name__c = null;`) in this statement(`if(!String.isBlank(ld.name))`) will not be covered.  Another example would be this line `if(contactNamesToLeadsMap.containsKey(ld.name))` will not be true when your test runs because you are only inserting one record so this line will not be covered either: `leadsForPartner = contactNamesToLeadsMap.get(ld.name);`

> **Checking Code Coverage**
>
> The Developer Console retrieves and displays code coverage information
>   from your organization. Code coverage results come from any tests
>   you’ve run from an API or from a user interface (for example, the
>   Developer Console, the Force.com IDE, or the Apex Test Execution
>   page). To clear the current results, click Test | Clear Test Data.
>   When you edit a class, the code coverage for that class is cleared
>   until you run the tests again.
>
> You can view code coverage in several places in the Developer Console.
>
> - The Tests tab includes an Overall Code Coverage panel that displays    the code coverage percentage for every Apex class in your
>     organization that has been included in a test run. It also displays
>     the overall percentage.
> - Double-click a completed test run to open a Tests Results view that    displays the tested class, the tested method, the duration, result
>     (skip, pass, or fail), and an optional error message. If the test
>     failed, a Stack Trace column shows the method and line number at
>     which the test failed.
> - To view line-by-line code coverage for an Apex class, open the class.    The Code Coverage menu will include one or more of the
>     following    options depending on the tests you have implemented:
>
>   -- None
>
>   -- All Tests: The percentage of code coverage from all test runs.
>
>   -- className.methodName: The percentage of code coverage from a method    executed during a test run.
>
> Lines of code that are covered by tests are blue. Lines of code that
>   aren’t covered are red. Lines of code that don’t require coverage (for
>   example, curly brackets, comments, and System.debug calls) are left
>   white.

Comment: So I tried to update the test code but now i'm only getting 66% Covered.  I'm struggling on this last part.  I've added new test class and screenshot of covered code.

Comment: @AndrewSims your test class didn't change too much really, still only a single insert test. In your test class you would need to create several leads in a list and insert that list. In that list you would want to make sure that at least 2 of the leads have the same name and that will help you reach line 8 of your trigger. Line 15 will only be hit if you insert a lead that has no name. Also in your new test you are setting the fields the trigger should be setting, you need to make it match your scenario. There is a contact "John Smith" and a new lead came in where Name = "John Smith".

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  I was able to update test class to get 100% coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate method for **each branch** of your if-else statements or one method that has data in it that creates those respective conditions in order to get full coverage on your trigger.